# How does the site handle old questions with 0 answers, and won't be deleted under current policy?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, unanswered-questions, ethics

From the "How can a post be deleted?" [faq answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222):

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.

What should we do with questions that won't be deleted as they have more than two comments? 'Cause they'll just flow to the end of the unanswered tabs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really simple: we should answer those questions.

And if we don't know the answer or don't want to answer, we should let it live and stay in the "end of the unanswered tabs" until answered.

There is a reason for the thresholds, and if a question doesn't meet them, I really don't think we should close/delete it ourselves just because it didn't get enough upvotes.

Comment: So, should we change the Community User so it `bumps non-negatively scored questions that have no answers or no answers with a scoring more than 0.` ?

Comment: @Malandy No and not sure how it's related to your question. Like I said, nothing should be changed, users who actively search for old questions with no answers will find such questions and answer if they can/want to.

Comment: But, there might be people who could answer, but just never check the unanswered tab...

Comment: @Malandy same reasoning: there is a good reason for the current criteria what questions get auto bumped. Changing this to allow more questions will just clutter the front page. I'm not saying that question with 0 score and 20 comments is **good**, I'm just saying it's not bad enough to be auto deleted, so for the sake of those seeking such questions (or just for search purpose) it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: If you come across a bad old question that meets those requirements, you don't need to close/delete vote them. Just give them a downvote and they will be auto-deleted within the next 7 days when the other roomba script runs. I agree that if the questions are on topic and don't fit a close reason, and are not crap, that you should let them be and hopefully someone will answer them... but I'd say at least 15% of them should probably just be given a downvote to put them out of their misery.

Comment: @Roomba good point, but guess each case is on its own - can't really give a general guideline about it. :)